# Rails error "bundle install" on W8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

i just installed rails, the Run 'bundle install' message keeps showing in the screen.
 How do i fix it>? Please help me
When i write the command bundle install rails says that there are some missing gems.

I am running the command 'bundle install' in the C:\sites\sample>

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cGWz4fT.png

Comment: Please put the commands you are running in your question so that this question may be found by others with the same issue in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is recently a common issue on windows. Easiest solution, get rid of Windows and get yourself a nice UNIX based system. As far as i understand it it is caused by RubyGems changing CertificateAuthority, which windows has some issue with.

There are three solutiions:

### The right one:

Install newer version of rubygems from https://rubygems.org/pages/download. Note: You cannot use `gem` command, you need to download it manually.

### Will work as well

Manually update ssl certificate.

1. Get a certificate from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem)
2. Locate `GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem` file. The easiest way is to run `gem which rubygems`, navigate to given folder and then to `rubygems/ssl_cert`.
3. Edit the content of file above with the certificate from step 1.
4. Party

### Hacky one, not recommended:

Another solution, edit your Gemfile. On top you'll find:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`
Change it to:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

And all should work (for a while. Ruby is not designed to work smoothly with Windows)